# @media (max-width 680px){ } is not what I expected: -52P-1 (when the screen smaller than 580px) is my expectation of -52p-2

Tags: css, flexbox

The image should in the center like the text.

My code is here: https://huijingjia.github.io/-52P-2/

I expect to make the website responsive, when the screen'width smaller than 580px, imgs and texts should adjust to the screen like the pictures showed.
However, the imgs are leaned to the right side of the screen.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and edit your question accordingly. Some tips: Include code, and include inline images, not external links.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you included your CSS code and not your external link in order for people to help more easily.

I think in your case you need to set the margin left and right to auto to center your image something like this

```
@media (max-width: 580px)
.card img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

you can also write in 1 line

```
@media (max-width: 580px)
.card img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;  /* top and bottom | left and right */
    display: inline;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

you can learn more in the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin